# Late created animations angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-animation

I have some code that creates and registers some animations inside a controller. Unfortunately, whenever I register an animation inside a controller, it does not seem to initialise (The function never gets called.)

I have created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uHrySh5zvZZF6Oxi7o7d) to illustrate the issue. In this, I call"createAnim1" outside the controller and the animation functions correctly. I call "createAnim2" inside a controller, and the animation does not function.

```
createAnim1();
app.controller('main', function($scope) {
  createAnim2(); //This animation does not work
});
```

The createAnim function are in the form:

```
app.animation('.anim1', function() {
    return {
        ...
    }
});
```

Am I missing something obvious? The $animate and $animateProvider documentation don't seem to contain anything relevant to this.

I assume this has to do with the fact that a compilation has already happened, and some step required to initialise the animations is being missed? Is there some way to get around this?

PS: I have only been using angular since last week, so I'm not well versed on the internals.

Edit:
After the comments from Alex, I think it is worth clarifying what I am trying to do:

I have some code which generates css class animation selectors and appends them to the document head. If the browser does not support transitions, the code generates a jquery animation equivalent. I have tried to create a factory to expose this code via DI, and it is when this code is run (From inside a controller) the animation is never able to trigger (The initialisation code is never run).

Comment: I am not an expert with those but I think you should not use `app.animation` in another function. You should register all the animations normally and then perhaps delay them with a service, I think you might be able to inject a service in your `.animation` methods. You cannot nest app.foo() in angularJS.

Comment: @AlexC thanks for the reply. Could I ask where you found information about the nesting? (The app.foo part of your comment). The goal here is to create a module that can handle both css animations and jquery animations from the same code (The module works when it I mock the dependencies and instantiate it outside of any angular modules.)

Comment: I thought that was obvious just by looking at the general DI design of angularJS. There are other things you cannot do, for instance you cannot inject a controller into another controller, or inject a directive in a controller. You should understand that angularJS is a framework and not just a library like jQuery, there are rules for what you put inside each angularJS component. Maybe someone will prove me wrong by showing a way to hack around it, but I think you should stick with the supported design patterns. :)

Comment: By the way, I wish those things were better documented. I have yet to find a place where all those things are stated clearly.

Comment: @AlexC I think part of the problem is how new I am to angular. I am still feeling out the best way of doing things. Thanks for taking the time to show me the way :)

Comment: it's ok, we all start somewhere. I am no expert either. If I was more comfortable with javascript animations, I would have edited your plnkr already. Hopefully someone else will.